# Magento 2 no me carga los estilos en modo "developer"

Tags: php, magento2

Tengo una tienda con Magento 2 en un servidor con Ubuntu 16.04 + PHP 7.0 y no sé porque cuando activo el modo desarrollador ejecutando:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

no se me cargan los estilos ni los JS y cuando cambio de modo ejecutando el comando:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

sí que funciona pero necesito que me los cargue en modo desarrollador para no tener que cambiar de modo cada vez que hago un cambio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando Magento 2 está en modo developer, los archivos de la carpeta pub/static no son generados como en el modo production, en cambio son generados enlaces simbólicos hacia las fuentes de estos mismos.

El punto de entrada para la generación de dichos enlaces simbólicos ocurre en pub/static.php y en nginx esta es la regla que se encarga de dicho comportamiento:

```
location /static/ {
...
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
```

Hay varias cosas por revisar:

- Permisos de pub/static y pub/static.php
- Configuración del servidor web (Nginx o Apache), ver configuraciones sugeridas por Magento: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/nginx.conf.sample y http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/apache.html
- Que se esté "ejecutando" pub/static.php, generalmente está relacionado con el punto anterior

Comment: Hola @Shaz, gracias por tu respuesta. Los permisos creo que los tengo bien y el parámetro **AllowOverride está en All**. También he cambiado el usuario y el grupo de manera que apache2 pueda escribir dentro de pub/* y los permisos de static.php están en **775** y pertenecen al mismo usuario que la carpeta **/pub: www-data:www-data**. Intenté hasta crear los enlaces simbólicos mediante ssh pero tampoco me los carga. He visto que cuando accedo al archivo: **miweb.com/pub/static.php** recibo un error y no se si tiene algo que ver: **Requested path '' is wrong**

Comment: Al final creo que eran los permisos porque copié los archivos de la carpeta /pub que tenía en otro magento y empezó a funcionar.